# Emacs relative path in autoloads vs. adding to load-path

Tags: emacs, autoload, dot-emacs

Say I have a site-lisp directory in which there are a subdirectories containing various elisp packages.  Until now I have been generating a single "loaddefs.el" file in the root of my site-lisp directory containing all the autoloads from the subdirectories, and compiling the contents of each subdir.  This creates an autoload file that looks like

```
;;; loaddefs.el --- automatically extracted autoloads
;;
;;; Code:

;;;### (autoloads nil "some-mode/some-mode" "some-mode/some-mode.el"
;;;;;;  (22412 1663 0 0))
;;; Generated autoloads from some-mode/some-mode.el

(autoload 'some-mode "some-mode/some-mode" "\
Major mode for some ranodom mode.

\\(fn)" t nil)
```

... and it goes on until reaching the local variables part.  Then, in my init file I just load the loaddefs.el file.

However, I noticed that the help for functions autoloaded like this says they are interactive autoloaded functions, but doesn't mention compiled, even when the contents of all the subdirectories is compiled.  From looking through package.el, I gathered that relative paths such as these are appended to each item in the load-path consecutively until the autoloaded item is found.

I couldn't find how autoloads are loaded by packages managed in the elpa directory, where autoloads for each package are in separate directories.  How does package-initialize load the autoloads?  And, is it more efficient to simply add each subdirectory to the load-path and create separate autoloads for each?